# Shell script to take backup only in secondary server of mongodb after replica set implementation

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

How can I take backup only on secondary server after the implementation of Replica set?
Based on voting the primary and secondary server will keep on changing, so always I want to check the secondary IP address and want to take backup on that machine.

Can anyone please help on this?

Comment: Hi Venugopal Seetharaman; would it be an option to change your replica set configuration, to make one of the nodes lower-priority? That way, you could be sure that node will be secondary.

Answer (score 3):

Just pass the url to secondary server for [`mongodump`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#bin.mongodump) as the `--host` parameter.

> If the string passed to --host contains a list of mongod instances,
>   but does not include the replica set name as a prefix to the host
>   string, mongodump reads from the nearest node by default.

Example:

```
mongodump --host "rep2.example.net:27017"
```

---

The other way (if you can't define the hardcoded address to secondary server) is to define the [read preference mode](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-preference/#replica-set-read-preference-modes). For that you need to set [`readPreference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption-mongodump-readpreference) parameter as [`secondary`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-preference/#secondary) (or better to use [`secondaryPreferred`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-preference/#secondaryPreferred) instead of it).

Example:

```
mongodump --host "replSet/rep1.example.net:27017,rep2.example.net:27017,rep3.example.net:27017" --readPreference secondary
```

Comment: I think the OP's point is that they can't hard-code a node, because they won't be sure which node is secondary.

Comment: @VinceBowdren Thanks for the remark, for some reason I did not think about it. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `mongodump` with `--readPreference` parameter:

```
mongodump --host "<replsetname>/<node1>,<node2>,<node3>" --readPreference "secondary"
```

Note that:

- You must supply the replica set form of the [`--host` parameter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption-mongodump-host)
- Specify the [read preference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-preference/#replica-set-read-preference-modes). This example uses `secondary` to dump strictly from a secondary node, but it's also possible to set it to `secondaryPreferred` so that it will dump from the primary if the secondaries cannot be contacted for some reason.